# Algorithm to travel from N1 -> N2->N1 with minimum time

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

This is the question that I found from a source.
There are N number of nodes. Each node connected to at least one other node. There is an Odia ‘O’ who does not know Chinese language but having a sensor, which can interact in Chinese only. 
Suppose you know both Odia and Chinese.
The person has to go from node N1 to node N2 (Some arbitrary two nodes) and after staying 10 min at N2 he has to come back again to N1.
The sensor can find the distance from current node to its immediate node.
Once the sensor reached to N2 it will be deactivated.
The distance and the time to travel is directly proportional.
**Design an algorithm to travel from N1 -> N2->N1 with minimum time. Use the sensor and help O.**

[Image as given in the problem statement...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RuBX.jpg)

The algorithm is to find the shortest path but **I am unable to get the problem statement.**

Comment: Is "a source"  = "homework" ? (from shortest path of graph theory maybe)

Comment: If you think this is a homework, well it is not, I got this question from the web, and I am asking it as I am unable to understand the question as to what to do and what not to!

Comment: Please link the question.

Comment: As I understand it, the "minimum time" is somewhat ambiguous. The traveller has only limited information and has to do some trial and error. It is unlikely he will go to N2 in the minimum achievable time. Even when going back the true minimum may not be achievable.

Comment: @Henry oops, I delete the answer once I see your comment, indeed I do not know if there is an algorithm which can find the optimal solution on the fly, without knowing the cost between all nodes beforehand...

Comment: @Henry can u please elaborate it? What's the use of the sensor? Does it have any significance? In one statement its said that the sensor can interact in Chinese and in the another it says the sensor's job is to find out the distance from current node to its immediate node.

Comment: @saswat23 The text is very unclear, I ignored the part about languages completely (since I did not understand it). I guess the sensor can only give the distance to the immediate neighbour nodes (also this part is somewhat unclear in the text).

Comment: Thank you @Henry, I suppose the sensor is used to calculate the distance between current node and its immediate node and can only interact in Chinese language! I am not sure though!

Comment: @saswat23 Yes it can only interact in chinese language but that's not the main point. The main point is the sensor can only detect the distance between current node and its neighbor nodes, means you do not have all information (distances) of the graph beforehand yet you are asked to find the optimal solution...

Comment: @shole Yes, that's the question I hope. Thanks ;)

Comment: @saswat23 If you got a solution sometime, could you please post here, seriously I want to know how to do this task with that little information provided (in a reasonable run time)